# SRWebClient Image Upload Cannot convert value

Tags: swift

I'm begining with ios and after converting my project to Swift 3 I'm getting this error message

> Cannot convert value of type '(AnyObject!, Int) -> Void' to expected argument type 'SRWebClient.SuccessHandler?'

I can't figure out what's wrong, how can I fix this?

```
if(image != nil) {
    let imageData: Data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image!)!
    SRWebClient.POST(url)
        .data (imageData, fieldName:fieldName, data: d)
        .send({(response:AnyObject!, status:Int) -> Void in // Error message here
            //process success response
            (self.delegate?.ApiCallCompleted!(response as! NSDictionary, error: nil))!;
            },failure:{(error:NSError!) -> Void in
                //process failure response
                self.delegate?.ApiCallCompleted!(["":""], error: error);
            })
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SuccessHandler` expression syntax is `public typealias SuccessHandler = (Any?, Int) -> Void`

so change this expression `(response:AnyObject!, status:Int) -> Void in` to `(response: Any, status:Int) -> Void in`

for more check [SRWebClient](https://github.com/sraj/Swift-SRWebClient/blob/master/SRWebClient/SRWebClient.swift)